# How to remove/delete geo-location meta data from photos?

Tags: photos, photos.app, geolocation, metadata

Occasionally someone emails me a photograph with their geo data included. I don't record this on my photos, so it's weird to have just one image randomly include location.

In previous versions of macOS Photos app, I believe it was in the menubar under `Image / Location / Remove Location`. Now (macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra, Photos 3.0) I only see `Image / Location / Hide Location`.

Is there another way to do this, in Photos app or perhaps Finder or Terminal?